# SQL - select where condition is true but delete if there is another row that breaks condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched hours on the internet but I found nothing that would help me. Here is my problem...

**My table**

```
/ id / number / idobject /
/ 1  /   50   /    2     /
/ 2  /   60   /    2     /
/ 3  /   70   /    2     /
/ 4  /   80   /    1     /
/ 5  /   10   /    2     /
/ 6  /   20   /    1     /
/ 7  /   90   /    3     /
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE number > 50
```

**Result i want**

```
/ id / number / idobject /
/ 7  /   90   /    3     /
```

I want only idobjects with at least 1 idobject true(>=50) and no idobject false

Comment: What consitutes true or false

Comment: Show us your desired output table.  The rules you gave are confusing.

Comment: What would be your expected result, if you add one more row into your data with `id=8, number=70, idobject=3` (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40dda2/5)

Comment: Only one result idobject 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i get it,you want idojects with at least 1 idobject true(>=50) and no idobject false

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id ,MAX(number) as number,idobject 
FROM t
GROUP BY idobject
HAVING SUM(number <50)=0
AND SUM(number >=50)>0
```

EDIT

if you have more than 1 idobject true,you can replace MAX with GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: nice. I was on it but you beaten me. Your solution works. [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/960ef3/2)

Comment: You are lucky to get the correct result, because of sample data. You will get only one row each `idobject`, and your `id` and `number` might not even come from the same row. I wonder if OP really wants such results.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Well if he wants different results he can comment.One way is to remove the aggregate functions and use IN for the respective idobject

Comment: The sqlfiddle sample selecting only `idobject` makes more sence (IMHO).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Well that was my original answer,but given the data i added max.The edit is not visible becasue it was done too quick

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I need only `idobject`, then i add `INNER JOIN` to  combine rows from another table **Another table**  `/ idobject / price / date /`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a NOT IN clause.

```
select idobject from table where idobject not in(select idobject from table where number<50);
```

Comment: Isnt this slower than Mihai solution?

Comment: It is. There is a subquery involved. Now that Mihai has solved it, the best I could do here is use a NOT EXISTS :-P

Comment: You can't say that it is slower, just because you use a subquery. Subqueries are often used to prefilter data and to increase the performance.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Since the same table is scanned twice, once presumably with indexes(inner query), and then without (outer query uses not clause, so no index), I presumed it would be slower than mihai's aggregate.

Comment: The problem in this specific case is that either `number<50` or `not in(..)` won't be very selective (too many matches). Even if both columns are indexed - a full table scan might be faster than two index searches. But if the conditions would be `... where idobject in(... where number=50)` the query should be pretty fast. So all i want to say is that a subquery is **not allways** a performance killer.